# Understanding protected branches push and merge role attributions

Tags: gitlab, branch, roles

In Gitlab (Community Edition v16.6.2), protected branches configuration page, we can assign a role to "Allowed to merge" and to "Allowed to push and merge".

Allowing to push implies allowing to merge. This is why "Allowed to push" was renamed into "Allowed to push and merge". See
[Change "Allowed to push" to "Allowed to push and merge"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/388103).

**Question**

Is there any difference if we set a larger role in "Allowed to merge" than in "Allowed to push and merge" or is it strictly equivalent as if we set the same role in "Allowed to merge" and in "Allowed to push and merge".

[image: conf1]

[image: conf2]

Stated otherwise, is the two configurations above strictly equivalent or are there any implications of choosing one or the other configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

The two settings are not the same.

- "Allowed to merge" means that a member with the stated role can click on the "Merge" button on a merge request to merge the changes into a protected branch.
- "Allowed to push and merge" is more permissive. The member with the stated role can *additionally* push directly to protected branches without requiring them to create a new branch/MR.

I suppose in the particular screenshots you have, they would essentially do the same thing, but the recommendation is to set it what you would want it to be if only one "existed" since they can be changed separately.

[The protected branches documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#when-a-branch-matches-multiple-rules) does a good job of explaining what happens when you have multiple rules that match, so I won't reiterate everything here, only that

> the most permissive rule determines the level of protection for the branch

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I understand `the most permissive rule determines the level of protection for the branch` is used when multiple wildcard protected branch apply to a single branch. My question is more about the difference between the two configurations represented by the screenshots. If there is no difference why allowing the user to set these different configurations?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You're right that in the screenshots you have, it should essentially be the same. The settings are independent of each other so don't check whether they overlap inherently. The more permissive "Allowed to push and merge" should apply in both cases.